# When reviewing a suggested edit, how do I tell what question or answer it relates to?

Tags: feature-request

The site asked me to review and approve/reject an edit suggested by a user who doesn't have permission to make the edit directly.  However, I can't find enough information for me to make an informed judgement.

In particular, I can't figure out how to tell what question page or what answer the edit is supposed to apply to.  Is there some way to do that that I'm missing?  Here's a screenshot that illustrates what I mean:

[image: A confusing screen image]

I couldn't find a link to the original answer (before the edit is applied), or to the question page where this answer would appear (i.e., which this edit would apply to).  Am I being dense?

**Update**: I'd like to make a feature suggestion, to improve the usability of this screen:

- It would be great if there was some way I could have used to learn what the string "ids tag wiki" meant.

I now understand that the string "ids tag wiki" means that this edit was for the wiki for the tag `ids`.  I don't know how I was supposed to have inferred that, having never seen this before; that string just looked like a jumble of letters to me, with no apparent meaning.  Therefore, I suggest that it would be useful to provide some kind of indicator to help users understand what "ids tag wiki" refers to.

- One very simple suggestion: make "ids tag wiki" be a link to the wiki for that tag.
- If you want to be even more helpful, you could add a "help" link that answers the question: "What's a tag wiki?".  I'd never heard of the phrase "tag wiki" before, so I wasn't able to parse this as "the tag wiki for `ids`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion definitely makes sense, since the suggested edits were not for any question or answer at all! On the left hand side you can see the blue text indicating "ids tag wiki". The tag had no existing entry, so the diff shows all new content.

Comment: The UI could be clearer. :-)     P.S. What's an "ids tags wiki"?

Comment: @D.W. The tag wiki entry for the `[ids]` tag. Clearly. :)